# How can I tell if a response stream is valid for creating an image in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, image, httpwebresponse

I'm pulling an image from a web server using VB.NET, and everything works fine when I debug on my workstation.  However, when I deploy the app to my server it is failing.  It appears it can't draw the image from the stream with an error of "Parameter is not valid", which occurs in the GetImage line below in the try catch block.  I know the image can be retrieved on the server because if I put the URL in a browser address bar the image displays just fine.  How can I go about troubleshooting the response stream to determine what is going on?

```
Function GetImage(ByVal URL As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim Response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
    GetImage = Nothing

    Try
        Request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
        Response = CType(Request.GetResponse, System.Net.WebResponse)

        If Request.HaveResponse Then 
            If Response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then 
               GetImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Response.GetResponseStream)
            End If
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
        txtActivity.Text = "Error retrieving image from URL " & URL & vbCrLf & e.ToString() & vbCrLf & txtActivity.Text
        Exit Try
    Finally

    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Try writing the failing response stream directly to a file, and then viewing that file in a text editor.

Comment: Okay, I wrote the stream to a file using Response.GetResponseStream.CopyTo(myfilestream), and both on my workstation and on the server they produce a file that can be viewed as a bitmap image.  Both files appear to be identical.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Getting this specific error when it attempts to draw the bitmap, if it helps any:  
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at APSAdvices.MainForm.GetImage(String URL) in C:\Projects\AutoPoster\APSAdvices\Controls\MainForm.vb:line 701

Comment: Use a hex editor to compare the file output to the original image file.  I've had problems like this before where there is an extra null character at the end that messes up Image.FromStream, but other apps are able to read.

Comment: I did use WinMerge to compare the two files created from the streams I mention above, and it shows they are identical. The stream succeeds on my workstation, though, and fails on the server.